# Why can't we create an object with the "this" keyword in java?

Tags: java, oop, this, factory

I've seen places where object creation factories are implemented by having a reference to the class object and having a `create` method which does this:`class.newInstance()`, which uses reflection, and might not be efficient compared to calling the default constructor directly.

If java supported something like `return new this();`, I could implement this in a parent class and that would work as a factory method (and would throw an exception if there is no such constructor as does `class.newInstance()`).

Why isn't such a thing supported?

PS: My first question in stackOverflow :)

Comment: Why? Because James Gosling designed Java that way.

Comment: this is a reference to an object and not to a type

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why is `new` not good enough keyword for you?

Comment: @darijan that's not the point he's trying to make. It's not about `new`, it's about calling the constructor of a class without knowing the class name.

Comment: you can use `this.getClass().newInstance()` instead

Comment: About your example, when you were in the parent class constructor the object would already been created (even if not initialized yet). So you would be creating a new, different object.

Comment: why the obsession with `this`? Just call `getClass().newInstance()`

Comment: @Bohemian Reflection is not as efficient as normal constructor call

Comment: @SJuan76 The point is, I am not in a parent class constructor, I am in a method which is something like "createObject" which returns a new object of that class.

Comment: @radiantRazor so what? it's not all about efficiency. I wager it's efficient *enough* given its brevity.

Answer (score 4):

As designed, the `this` keyword is valid only in the context of an instance. Its type is the type of the class within which it occurs.

From the Java Language Specification:

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

If you want to create a new object using the default constructor, you can call it directly.

```
 return new MyType();
```

If you want to create a clone of an object, you may be able to use the `Object.clone()` method.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the PHP equivalent of *self*. The self keyword refers to the class the code is currently executing in, thats very roughly equivalent to the result of getClass().

Comment: Not sure, given his reference to a parent class. There have been times when I've wanted something similar to *self* in Java, but primarily to reduce typing. If I understand correctly, in Java it would be merely syntatic sugar.

Comment: While this is a reference to the current object, this() can be use to call the constructor of the current class (As is used by constructors to call other constructors). I was talking about `this` in this context.

Comment: @radiantRazor - When you asked about `return new this();`, were you trying to get a superclass method called on one instance to return a second instance?

Comment: No, I was expecting the code `public A create(){return new this()}` to return an object of the correct type depending on whether the method is called on an Object of type `A` or on a an object of a calss `B` subclass of `A`. So, I am expecting `new A().create()` to return an object of type A and `new B().create()` to return an object of type B (given that `B` extends `A`) and so on

Comment: @radiantRazor - I see. You want a method which returns a new instance of the same class, created with the default constructor. The new instance is not a copy. (If it were, you could just use `clone()`.) You'd like to have a single definition of this method. Java allows that, at the cost of reflection. If you measure the performance of using reflection, and find that it does not meet your requirements, you'll need to have a definition in each subclass. You could encourage that by following the common OO guideline to make all non-leaf classes abstract.

Answer (score 2):

You can get close using `this.getClass().newInstance()`

However, this approach is not recommended. For one thing, it requires that the class has a default constructor.

Comment: `this.` is redundant. Simply `getClass().newInstance()` will do.

Comment: true, but the OP was asking about `this`, so I left it in

Comment: I think he uses `this` to express ability of doing this via `this` reference

Comment: @hoaz this is confusing

Comment: as long as `this` isn't confusing :-)

Comment: Why does this require a default constructor ? I mean you could have a newInstance with parameters easily

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful you can do that by manually invoking a constructor: `myclass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, boolean.class).invoke("FooBar", true)`, but the `class.newInstance()`method uses the default constructor only and fails if none is present.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks for the clarifciation, I wasn't aware this was reflection method at all, I just assumed that this was referring to a static newInstance method in the returned class

Answer (score 1):

according to java doc

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

So this is holding the current instance of object. it is not a type.

But when you are initializing a object you need to initialize it with the class type. like

```
ClassType c = new ClassType();
```

So these two things are totally different. that's why you can't initialize with `this`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is how could you create the `instance` of a class without knowing  `class name` ? however `this` keyword is applicable to `current object` which you have not created yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because when you use "this" means that the object is already created, so you cannot use "new this" to create another.